# Указатели и функции с++

Tags: c++

Задача:
В одномерном массиве , состоящем из n целых элементов , вычислить :

• номер максимального элемента массива ;

• умножения элементов массива , расположенных между первым и вторым нулевыми элементами .

Превратить массив так , чтобы в первой половине располагались элементы , стоявшие в нечетных позициях, а во второй половине - элементы, стоявшие в четных позициях .

Это я сделал,но проблема в том что мне нужно при выполнении операций над элементами использовать указатели. Обраработку массива выполнить в функции. Функцию в главной программе вызвать через указатель. Память под массив выделить динамично.
И почему то сортировка некорректно работает.Помогите исправить ошибки.

Вот код

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{   srand(time(0));
    int A[25],i,max,i_max=0,p[25],z;
    for (i=0;i<25;i++)
    {
        A[i]=rand()%20-5;
        cout<<A[i]<<" ";
    }
    cout <<endl;
    max=A[0];
    for (i=0;i<25;i++)
    if(max<A[i])
    {
       max=A[i];
       i_max=i;
    }
    cout<<"Max nomer:"<<i_max+1;
    int j=0;
    for (i=0;i<25;i++)

    if(A[i]==0)
    {
        p[j]=i;
        j++;
    }
    if (j<2) cout<<"\nrezultat ymnojenya:Net resh\n"; else
    {
       z=1;
       for(i=p[0]+1;i<p[1];i++)
          z*=A[i];
       cout<<"\nrezultat ymnojenya: "<<z;
    }
    cout<<"\nOtsort masiv:\n";
    for(i=0;i<25;i++)
        if(i%2==0)cout<<A[i]<<" ";

    for(i=0;i<25;i++)
        if(i%2!=0)cout<<A[i]<<" ";
    cout<<endl;
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: вы просите сделать все за вас. разбейте вашу задачу на более общие вопросы и задайте отдельно то что у вас не получается или вы не понимаете

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну... скажем так: постарался сделать, не меняя ваш подход, хотя руки чесались :)

```
int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    int *A = new int[25], i, max, i_max = 0, z;

    for (i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
        A[i] = rand() % 20 - 5;
        cout << A[i] << " ";
    }

    cout << endl;
    max = A[0];

    for (i = 1; i < 25; i++)
        if (max < A[i])
        {
            max = A[i];
            i_max = i;
        }

    cout << "Max nomer:" << i_max + 1;

    int j1 = -1, j2 = -1;

    for (i = 0; i < 25; i++)
        if (A[i] == 0)
        {
            if (j1 < 0)
            {
                j1 = i;
            }
            else
            {
                j2 = i;
                break;
            }
        }

    if (j2 < 0)
    {
        cout << "\nrezultat ymnojenya:Net resh\n";
    }
    else
    {
        z = 1;

        for (i = j1+1; i < j2; i++)
        {
            z *= A[i];
        }

        cout << "\nrezultat ymnojenya: " << z;
    }

    cout << "\nOtsort masiv:\n";

    for (i = 0; i < 25; i++)
        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            cout << A[i] << " ";
        }

    for (i = 0; i < 25; i++)
        if (i % 2 != 0)
        {
            cout << A[i] << " ";
        }

    cout << endl;

    delete[] A;
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Сортировку вашу не понял - если вам достаточно вывода, то вроде как и так работает? В чем некорректность-то?

Comment: Спасибо больше!Я просто подумал,что нужно что бы в первой половине стояли парные элементы массива,а во второй - не парные.